# Python input function in Eclipse not accepting input from console

Tags: python, eclipse, input, pydev

I am just learning Python and am using Eclipse version 4.15.0. I have entered the following code:

```
i=int(input("Enter an integer number:"))
print(i)
```

When I run it, "Enter an integer number:" appears in the console, but when I enter "123" in the console, and rerun, 123 does not print in the console. I have tried this a number of times but no input appears. I have also tried it with strings, but again my input will not print.

Comment: You enter `123` and rerun?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: And the 123 just vanishes - it doesn't print on the line below, as the instructor on my online class indicates it should.

Comment: You should press enter key, not rerun the program.

Comment: Aha!!!! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to rerun.

Just press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.